# How to read soap response header

Tags: php, xml, cookies, soap, header

Getting response from one of the soap function php, after that sending this response as a parameter to another soap request, that time I need to extract the set-cookie from the previous response header here below my response header. I need to read set-cookie JSESSIONID element ?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Set-Cookie: **JSESSIONID=9A977E193F9B505B084D95C3028BAD0C.srv1816**;

Path=/webservices

Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 07:38:52 GMT

Set-Cookie: aeroID=12988141315553139361555313936504655;Path=/;
Expires=Sun, 09-Feb-2020 07:38:56 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just read your JSESSIONID cookie like so :

First get your cookies :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport
def cookieStore= HttpClientSupport.getHttpClient().getCookieStore()
```

Then just find the one that interest you

```
def cookies = cookieStore.getCookies()
def jsessionidCookie
cookies.each {
    if(it.name == "JSESSIONID")
        jsessionidCookie= it
}
```

Comment: looking php solution